# jquery conflict issue but i need both of them

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, codeigniter

How can i make two jquery both of them would work fine in my code. I have a conflict jquery thats why its not working fine. but when i erase the other one, the other one requires the other version of the jquery. From here i have a conflict jquery:

```
<script src="<?php echo base_url('assets/jquery/jquery-2.1.4.min.js')?>">
</script>
<script src="<?= base_url() ?>assets/manager/js/jquery.min.js">
</script>
```

If i delete the first one, my dropdown doesnt come out, if i delete the second one, the dropdown of my logout menu doesnt come out.

Comment: What is this: **<?= base_url() ?>** ?

Comment: i use codeigniter sir. sorry forgot to mention

Comment: Try switching them around or Google "jquery conflict".

Comment: thats why i asked here @Fred-ii-. whats the purpose of my question ?

Comment: What do you need us for then; find you links? Because that's what you need to do. That, or refactor your code.

Comment: @RaxWeber [Short hand echo](http://php.net/manual/en/function.echo.php). Also, OP, you'll need to refactor your code to harness one jQuery version. Mix-matching like this will end up costing you big time. Always be forward thinking and simplify your work-load, imagine in a years time if you continue to mix jQuery versions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try to save jquery in any other object. then use that object inside second jquery
like this

```
var jq=jQuery.noConflict();
```

now use this jq inside second jquery
after this save jq's value in jquery loke this

```
var jQuery=jq.noConflict();
```